# Extract Words from a string, then store in variables

Tags: c++

I am trying to store user input into a string and then use that string to store individual words into character variables which I will later use to set up a class object. To be clear, I'd like a method that doesn't include using vector or stringstream since I haven't touched on those subjects yet and I'm hoping there's a way to do this without those functions or the libraries they are included in.

The class I'm working with:

```
class Name
    {
        char* m_firstName{};
        char* m_middleName{};
        char* m_lastName{};
    }
```

So far the code I am using works, but obviously does not split up the names - I'm only able to send one string to one variable:

```
std::istream& Name::read(std::istream& istr){
        string input;
        getline(istr, input);
        char* firstName = new char[input.length() + 1];
        strcpy(firstName, input.c_str());
        set(firstName);

        return istr;
}
```

I need to be able to pull out words inside the string which will be delimited by a space. For example, if the input is "John Adam Smith", I'd like to be able to store "John", "Adam" and "Smith" inside of firstName, middleName and lastName character string variables respectively.

I will then be using those variables within a "set" function that I have for inserting the data into the class. I'm not worried about that part, once I have the variables I should be good to go. But I can't figure out how to separate the words inside the string.

Comment: You clearly know about `std::string` and their use. So why do you use pointers and explicit memory handling?

Comment: As for your problem, the standard stream extraction (input) operator `>>` separates on space. So you can use an input string stream for the line, and extract "words" using `>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Just go

```
 string first;
 string middle;
 string last;
 istr >> first >> middle >> last;
```

Things wrong in your current code:

- There is no way to get data into `Name` all the fields a re private and you have no methods.
- You should have strings everywhere, dont dynamically allocate char*s in c++ unless you have to. Dont juggle raw pointers.